# Client socket in Qt writes to ghost servers which cannot be traced on Wireshark

Tags: c++, linux, qt, sockets, networking

I am running a simple server on a linux box. And my client is running on a windows box. The address of the linux box is pingable from the windows box.

My client application which is written using qt sockets (the server is written using berkeley sockets) has the following code:

```
ConnectionManager::ConnectionManager()
{

    watchTowerSocket = new QTcpSocket();
    connect(watchTowerSocket, SIGNAL(connected()), this, SLOT(connected()));
    connect(watchTowerSocket, SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SLOT(disconnected()));
    connect(watchTowerSocket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readyRead()));
    connect(watchTowerSocket, SIGNAL(bytesWritten(qint64)), this, SLOT(bytesWritten(qint64)));

    qDebug() << "Connecting .. ";

    watchTowerSocket->connectToHost("198.168.101.230", 4400);

    if(!watchTowerSocket->waitForConnected(3000))
    {
        qDebug() << "Error" << watchTowerSocket->errorString();
    }
    else
    {
        watchTowerSocket->write("HELLO SERVER");
    }
}
```

I simply create the connection manager object and expect the connection to be established.

When I start my client I get following output on the console:

```
Connecting .. 
Connected .. 
we wrote ..  12
```

Now here is the doozey:

My server isn't even running! I don't know where the hell this client is connecting and writing to! Can you please help me understand what is happening?

I think somehow he address is getting misinterpreted. But I really don't know how to figure this out.

Let me also add that I have wireshark running and I have the filter `tcp.dstport == 4400` on it. When I do a telnet, I can see the packets in wireshark, but when I run my client, I don't see shit.

If my address was inaccessible, incorrect, some other error in the sockets then I would expect some error in connecting But the weird part is that that is not the case. My client seems to connect at the address specified. But Wireshark doesn't find any packets being sent and the server also doesn't receive any accept requests. But the client acts like it has connected! My question is, just where is the client connecting to? How do I figure this out?

Comment: Run a wireshark, filter by port and see where the traffic is going from client comp. Then do the same on target.

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky Could you kindly read my question again. I have edited it. And mentioned that I have already tested on wireshark. If you deem fit, please upvote the question. I think this is a real brain teaser. My sockets are drunk!

Comment: you can use rawcap (http://www.netresec.com/?page=RawCap) to capture loopback traffic as well. and you can use netstat to see if some process is listening on the target port

Comment: Your server NOT running !? check task manager and make sure server fully closed. (some times terminate threads not working and still running without gui.)

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky I don't know what is loopback traffic, but I have already run netstat and found that no process ever listens to it. That is not the problem though. My problem is where my qt socket is writing data. Why the qt soccket thinks it has connected to the host when clearly he host hasn't received any traffic. In fact the qt socket manages to successfully write to the server apparently even when the server isn't running

Comment: If your server is not running and ping permission is allowed so you can ping your server like this to check if your server is available `ping 198.168.101.230:4400`

Comment: @saeed The server address is pingable. If you read the question you will realise that the server running or not running is not the issue here.

Comment: @Chani I want to mentioned that make sure your server is not running, because In question you said my server is not running you don't know where the client is connecting, I think your server is running yet but you don't recognized it.

Comment: @saeed No, my server is definitely not running at the port specified. I have mentioned this several times in this thread.

Comment: Well please check your socket state via `qDenug() << yoursocket.state()` to check your socket state before wiatforconnect and after successful connect

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154902/discussion-between-saeed-and-chani).

Comment: You might want to not post real IP addresses here for security reasons.  Can you post the code that contains the "connected" and the "we wrote xx" messages ?

Comment: @xyious The connected and we wrote parts are just slots which are provided by tcpsocket class. I have just put one line implementation ..

Comment: Well I really can't diagnose code that I can not see.